# Not able to retrieve image in deployed version, while images are loading perfectly in react app running on localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

I have a MERN based web application deployed on Heroku. It has to load images dynamically with every post. But in production it's not loading images whereas when running on localhost I'm able to retrieve images.

Here is the [link](https://interviewlog.herokuapp.com/) to deployed website

This is how i m retrieving images from db.

```
 <img src={`/images/${post.image}`} alt={post.image} />
```

And here is how it is being served with express :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/')))
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}
```

Also I had noticed that when I had opened Developer mode in chrome for my deployed application and in sources I found that there is no images folder . This can be the reason for no images ?

Any solution or resource will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please may you include a [mcve] of the issue in the question?

Comment: I had provided link to the deployed application but what to provide for showing localhost

Comment: Where are the images located?

Comment: in the images folder inside the build directory.

Comment: Does express serve these files? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: yes express is serving these files

Comment: Please share that code?

Comment: just edited my code please check

Comment: Do the files exist in `/client/build/` directory?

Comment: yes they do, and that's why i am able to retrieve them while running on localhost. Also one thing that i noticed it that when i tried to inspect the sources with developer options of deployed app then i didn't find any images folder . This can be an issue ??  You can reproduce the same by visiting website from given link, inspect element and then click on source then pages from left most corner